# Child Theme not overwriting Parent theme php file

Tags: post-thumbnails, child-theme, child-pages

I'm new to Wordpress and how Child themes work. My child theme I am trying to overwrite two files in sub-directories. I've copied the parent files and edited them in child theme but changes are not reflected in parent theme. I'm trying to change the code for feature image sizes. I successfully changed the code in parent to test it and it works. But child theme isn't overriding it.

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/sahifa/framework/functions/theme-functions.php    
/public_html/wp-content/themes/sahifa-child/framework/functions/theme-functions.php
```

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/sahifa/framework/parts/related-posts.php
/public_html/wp-content/themes/sahifa-child/framework/parts/related-posts.php
```

1. Other question I had was do I need all the files in each folder to copied over?
2. Or Can I have the folder and just the one file I'm editing inside?

Update: I have no clue how to add the code by some suggestion made. I'd Appreciate if I could be shown. Here's a link to the files on my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDx62NxDIj3HlEkh3_txZa4mywW-2SlP/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/127oDdNQWxritIVXcvbHURANg5b4tpJCL/view?usp=sharing

Update:
I see in the parent theme this line of code in the functions.php file:

```
// Main Functions
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/theme-functions.php');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [override parent theme configuration in child functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309840/override-parent-theme-configuration-in-child-functions-php)

Comment: Update: I have no clue how to add the code by some suggestion made. I'd Appreciate if I could be shown. Here's a link to the files on my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDx62NxDIj3HlEkh3_txZa4mywW-2SlP/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/127oDdNQWxritIVXcvbHURANg5b4tpJCL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If the php file is gets `include`d or `require`d from functions.php file in parent theme all codes are added to runtime they are not replaced if you create files in similar directory structure.

## So, What can be replaced?

1. Only files called via `get_template_part()` can be replaced this way. This is also true for any file in [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
2. If the parent theme uses `add_action()` or `add_filter()` with function name you can remove them using `remove_action()` or `remove_filter()` and use your own replacements.
3. If parent theme uses `function_exists()` or `class_exists()` with an if encapsulating a function/class they can be replaced from your child themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: Update: I have no clue how to add the code by some suggestion made. I'd Appreciate if I could be shown. Here's a link to the files on my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDx62NxDIj3HlEkh3_txZa4mywW-2SlP/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/127oDdNQWxritIVXcvbHURANg5b4tpJCL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Update: I see in the parent theme this line of code:

// Main Functions
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/theme-functions.php');

Comment: instead of replacing whole file can you  replace the functionality? Please copy paste the file into a pastebin or any other online code repository. I think you might have to take different approach other then replacing file.

Comment: [link]https://hastebin.com/pojikodowe.xml`code`  parent code from functions and theme function included here. @Sisir thanks!

Comment: So, you need to remove image sizes? Why don't you try [`remove_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/)

Comment: no change the image sizes, which is why I was trying to override the parent theme sizes and have the functions.php file include theme-functions.php in the child theme. @Sisir

Comment: just remove the image sizes and add them with same name with sizes you want.