# File from parent theme imported to child theme doesn't work - any ideas?

Tags: php, functions, themes, child-theme

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress and I have such path in my theme: theme/includes/core-functions.php. I need to make changes in core-functions.php, so naturally I want to make them in child theme. I did it, but it doesn't work - I mean my code is right, because it works when I put it in parent theme. Of course the file is already uploaded in my child theme with all the necessary folders.

I tried calling core-functions.php in my child theme via the following code but it also doesn't work:

```
function corefunctions_script() { wp_enqueue_script( 'coreFunctionsScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/theme/includes/core-functions.php', array(), '1.0.0', true ); }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'corefunctions_script' );
```

I feel like I've tried everything. It should work but it doesn't - every other file in child theme does, but not this one. Does anyone have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [override parent theme configuration in child functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309840/override-parent-theme-configuration-in-child-functions-php)

Comment: You're enqueuing `core-functions.php`?  I mean, `wp_enqueue_script()` is for enqueuing a JS (`.js`) file..