# Change templates in a child theme

Tags: child-theme

I wanted to edit code in a theme. I have created a child theme. I want to edit a posts-3.php file but the changes are not reflecting. Do I have to create folder paths with the same name as that of the parent theme?

Comment: yes. Exactly the same folder/file structure is needed in ordre to properly edit files in child theme

Comment: Not all files are necessarily replaceable by a child theme. It depends on how the parent the works. See my answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309845/39152